# xpath find if node exists using PHP

Tags: php, dom, xpath

I want to find/create the xpath of all elements found after my query runs.

I tried, but I got stuck.

This code searches through all elements/nodes for any values that contain the letter 't'. If 't' is found , I would like to know the xpath of that element:

```
<?php

$dom = new DOMDocument();

@$dom->loadHTMLFile('http://www.linkbook.co/');

//use DOMXpath to navigate the html with the DOM
$dom_xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

$elements = $dom_xpath->query("//*[text()[contains(., 't')]]");
var_dump($elements);
if (!is_null($elements)) {

  foreach ($elements as $element) {
  var_dump($element);
    echo "\n[". $element->nodeName. "]";

    $nodes = $element->childNodes;
    foreach ($nodes as $node) {
      echo $node->nodeValue. "\n";
    }

  }

}

?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`DOMNode::getNodePath`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domnode.getnodepath.php) does exactly that, so try `echo $node->getNodePath()`.